# php check if value exsist in array, in another array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array dataImages which holds the arrays of image informations and looks like this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 104 
        [name] => sample-large-Test-1-a52d268be9ad9c.png 
        [user] => 31 
        [main_image] => 1 
    ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 105 
        [name] => sample-large-Test-1-a52d268bee6ba5.jpg 
        [user] => 31 
        [main_image] => 0 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 106 
        [name] => sample-large-Test-1-a52d268bf4c457.jpg 
        [user] => 31 
        [main_image] => 0 
    ) 
)
```

How can i check if in array `dataImages` is an image with `main_image === 1` and how can i show data for that image?

Comment: Look into array iteration.

Comment: [`array_filter`](http://uk3.php.net/array_filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in loop also:

```
foreach ($dataImages as $image){
    if ($image['main_image']) print_r($image)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better depending on what you want to do exactly (e.g. just loop), but one option is [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter) in which case you can do

```
function hasMain($var){
 return $var["main_image"];
}

print_r(array_filter($theArray, "hasMain"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getMainImage($images) {
    if(!is_array($images))
        return null;
    
    foreach($images as $image) {
        if(isset($image['main_image']) && $image['main_image'] == 1)
            return $image;
    }
    
    return null;
}

$mainImage = getMainImage($myImages);
```

Something like this should do the trick.

You can check if a variable contains an array by using is_array. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Answer (score 1):

```
$main_image = FALSE;
$img = '';

foreach($images as $image) {
  if ( $image['main_image'] == 1 ){
    $main_image = TRUE;
    $img = $image['name'];
    break;
  }
}
```